# Fetching YouTube transcript data from a list of video_ids

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function that can fetch the transcript of a youtube video. (You don't have to understand every line)

```
!pip install youtube_transcript_api
!pip install simplejson
from youtube_transcript_api import YouTubeTranscriptApi

import urllib.request
import json
import urllib


VideoID = 'LfC6pv8VISk'

def fetch_transcript():
    
    params = {"format": "json", "url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=%s" % VideoID}
    url = "https://www.youtube.com/oembed"
    query_string = urllib.parse.urlencode(params)
    url = url + "?" + query_string

    with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response:
        response_text = response.read()
        data = json.loads(response_text.decode())
        print('Titel: ' + data['title'])
    
    # retrieve the available transcripts
    transcript_list = YouTubeTranscriptApi.list_transcripts(VideoID)

    # iterate over all available transcripts
    for transcript in transcript_list:

        # fetch the actual transcript data
        data = transcript.fetch()
        print(data)         

    # filter for language 
    transcript = transcript_list.find_transcript(['en'])  

fetch_transcript()
```

**Output:** [{'text': "Okay, here we go. This one's gonna be\nquick. So get your coffee ready today.", 'start': 0.15, 'duration': 2.97...}]

Now I collected a list of video_ids like:

```
VideoID = ['LfC6pv8VISk', 'befUVytFC80', '4c_rKOaTquM']
```

How can I iterate over the list using my function?
My function only takes a single string like 'LfC6pv8VISk'

```
                                                           #the single string ↓

params = {"format": "json", "url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=%s" % VideoID}
```

for i in VideoID ... fetch_transcript() doesn't work. It feels so easy but I'm stuck.

Comment: @jupiterbjy I get the same bad 400 request. That's not normal

Comment: Mybad, I unknowingly put typo in url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try making your function accept video id as parameter.

You can safely ignore imports from typing, it's just for annotations.

```py
from typing import Iterable, Tuple, Dict, List, Any

from youtube_transcript_api import YouTubeTranscriptApi

import urllib.request
import json
import urllib


def fetch_transcript(vid_id) -> Tuple[str, List[Dict[str, Any]]]:
    params = {"format": "json", "url": f"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={vid_id}"}
    url = "https://www.youtube.com/oembed"

    query_string = urllib.parse.urlencode(params)
    url = url + "?" + query_string

    print(f"Fetching from {url}")

    with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response:
        response_text = response.read()
        title = json.loads(response_text.decode())["title"]

    # retrieve the available transcripts
    transcript_list = YouTubeTranscriptApi.list_transcripts(vid_id)

    return title, transcript_list.find_transcript(['en']).fetch()


def fetch_transcript_gen(vid_ids: Iterable):
    for video_id in vid_ids:
        yield fetch_transcript(video_id)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from pprint import pprint
    for title_, data_ in fetch_transcript_gen(['LfC6pv8VISk', 'befUVytFC80', '4c_rKOaTquM']):
        print(f"\nTitle: {title_}\nData length: {len(data_)}\n")
        pprint(data_)
```

Output:

```
Fetching from https://www.youtube.com/oembed?format=json&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DLfC6pv8VISk

Title: KILL Linux processes!! (also manage them) // Linux for Hackers // EP 7
Data length: 399

[{'duration': 2.97,
  'start': 0.15,
  'text': "Okay, here we go. This one's gonna be\n"
          'quick. So get your coffee ready today.'},
 {'duration': 4.4,
  'start': 3.12,
  'text': "We're gonna learn how to manage our\n"
          'processes, processes  and Lennox.'},
...

Fetching from https://www.youtube.com/oembed?format=json&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DbefUVytFC80

Title: you need to create a Cryptocurrency RIGHT NOW!! (Solana token)
Data length: 837

...

Fetching from https://www.youtube.com/oembed?format=json&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D4c_rKOaTquM

Title: putting 5G and MEC to the test!! (does it even matter??)
Data length: 741

...
```

Comment: This works great. Thanks a lot. :)
I didn't think of using the list in the parameter of the function.